Awesome Notifications (Flutter) not working in release mode
Everything works fine in debug mode, but after switching to release it throws error.
Error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(SHARED_PREFERENCES_NOT_AVAILABLE, class p5.b isn't parameterized, sharedPreferences.get, null)
It points to AwesomeNotifications().initialize(args) in main file.
What I tried:
Downgrade version of Awesome Notifications - didn't work.

This question is similar to: Proguard rules to avoid Shared Preferences Not Found in flutter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add this line to your android/app/build.gradle:
      buildTypes {
       release {
           minifyEnabled false
           shrinkResources false
       }
   }


this solution is temporary

This is working for me. I also deleted the proguard-rules.pro file which was causing errors on the android release version. Thank you!
